# How to set environment variable to run webdriverIO script

Tags: webdriver-io, allure, webdriver-io-v4

I am running my webdriverIO test cases using command
**npx wdio run .\wdio.conf.js --spec .\test\intel.test.js**

Now I want to pass environment variable for the same like ENV=qa

If I run command like this **ENV=qa npx wdio run .\wdio.conf.js --spec .\test\intel.test.js**
Getting error:

> ENV=qa : The term 'ENV=qa' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function,  script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path    was included, verify that the path is correct
> and try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - ENV=qa npx wdio run .\wdio.conf.js --spec .\test\intel.test.js

is there any way to set environment variable when we are using npx to run test cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass as like in the below command for user,key and baseurl which are all the allowed keys in wdio.conf.js.

npx wdio run .\wdio.conf.js --spec .\test\intel.test.js --user=automation

if you want to use any other parameters (like ENV as you mentioned), pls go with dotenv.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout dotenv package -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
and read this:
https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is set an environment variable in your console (that would work in CI as well depending on the tool your are using)

```
// In linux for example
export MY_VAR=foo
```

and in Webdriver.io simply access it with `process.env` like this

```
console.log(`MY_VAR value is: ${process.env.MY_VAR}`);
```

I get (last line)

```
...
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', acceptInsecureCerts: true },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome', acceptInsecureCerts: true }
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2022-11-18T16:59:50.392Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND maximizeWindow()
[0-0] 2022-11-18T16:59:50.393Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:9515/session/d70c54abaefa7549da6e3946f2b26ce8/window/maximize
[0-0] MY_VAR value is: foo
```

Quite handy and easy.